# Matlab: Apply an operation to each element of matrix

Tags: image, matlab, loops, matrix, cell

i have 100 image that I have read and store in a matrix of the form <128x128x100 Double> and I want to apply an operation on each image. how can I do? 
I have another matrix of the form <40x20 cell> witch contain 800 image and I want to do the same thing,  ie applying an operation on each image. 
I do not know how to make a loop that carries it. thank you for your help

Comment: I agree this is not the brightest of questions, but why the down votes?

Comment: What have you tried? I recommend the [Mathworks documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/) to get started... specifically on [`for`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/for.html) loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your function is in this form `function imageOut = someFunction(imageIn)`:

**First case:** (assuming `I` is a `MxNxP` matrix with `P` images, each `MxN`)

```
O = cell2mat(cellfun(@someFunction, num2cell(I, [1 2]), 'UniformOutput', false))
```

**Second case:** (assuming `I` is a `MxN` cell array, each cell contains an image)

```
O = cellfun(@someFunction, I, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

Answer (score 0):

The most straight forward aspproach is to use a [`for`-loop](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/loop-control-statements.html).
For the `128`-by-`128`-by-`100` matrix (let's call it `M`) you can do

```
for imi = 1:size(M,3)
    currImg = M(:,:,imi); % take a "slice" of M = an image
    % process currImg here...
end
```

For the `40`-by-`20` cell array (let's call it `C`) you can do

```
for ri = 1:size(C,1)
    for ci = 1:size(C,2)
        currImg = C{ri,ci}; % get an image stored in cell ri,ci
        % process currImg here...
    end
end
```

Notice the different modes of accessing matrices (using `()`) and accessing cell elements (using `{}`).

Answer (score 0):

This really really really depends on the operation you want to apply. For example, if you want to dilate each image with a 3x3 square, all you have to do is pass the 3D matrix and the 3x3 square.

```
imdilate (img, true (3, 3));
```

This simple example will apply dilation on all the 2D images of the matrix, it's all a matter of choosing the right structuring element (the `true (3, 3)`).  Of course, you can use a for loop too, but that's not how this language was meant to be used. And isn't the example above much more elegant than a loop?

A well designed function for the Matlab language should be handling this cases for you, and work across all images of a n-dimensional matrix. It is up to you to understand the operator and function well enough to make it do what you want.